# Does the following error indicate my system is compromised?

Tags: arch-linux, security, systemd, startup

```
[FAILED] Failed to Verify Integrity of password and group files. See 'systemctl status shadow.service' for details.
```

I get this message in T1 every time I start up the computer but I havn't noticed anything else amiss.  Does this mean my system is compromised?  If not what does it mean and what should I do (if anything) to fix it?

Computer is running Arch linux 64 bit.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status shadow.service` ?

Comment: Package removals can result in orphaned group and passwd files: you can run `grpck` and `pwck` to confirm and repair.

Comment: Gilles* shadow.service - Verify integrity of password and group files.  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/shadow.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)  Active: inactive (dead)